# Recent mortality

Tags: mortality, collecting-data

Recently there are a lot of datapoints regarding COVID-19 related deaths. However I am looking to see how big the impact of non-diagnosed patients is.

Therefore I want to evaluate the deaths (corrected for reported virus deaths) and see how these compare to the same period in recent years.

I understand it is best practice to avoid asking for specific data sets here, so I will keep my question as generic as possible and ask for leniency:

Does anyone know how to find (or search for) recent mortality statistics? Ideally this would be "per day per country up to today", but even "a total for February in a continent or city would already be insightful".

---

What have I tried so far:

1. Searching recent mortality, this only results in virus related statistics
2. Searching for several countries or WHO, this did not result in anything for this year

Comment: Perhaps ask on the [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) site? (e.g. [this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/human-mortality-database-around-the-world))

Comment: https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/deaths has weekly, monthly and more data for England & Wales.  The weekly registration figures have been below average from 17 January to 6 March, but that may have been affected by temperatures

Comment: You can refer to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/453879) regarding the same topic (i.e. fatality rate of COVID-19)

Comment: The referred question seems to focus more on missed living persons (which is also relevant) while I am looking more to identify missed deaths. @Henry That is very interesting, definitely consider posting it as an answer! (hopefully more wil follow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like the death toll is clearly showing up (yet).

For instance, Europe has almost up to 10 000 deaths *in a single day* during the peak of a heavy respiratory season, and the Covid-19 cases will only be a small bump, in relation to the overall burden of disease.

But, that would be playing down the impact of the virus. It is difficult to look at the overall death rate. Many people are dying every day. We can not easily compare a single cause to the total amount of deaths that are occurring.

Important to consider is that Covid-19 deaths have a non-homogeneous spatial distribution and locally there's a high density that's not clear in common (public) databases that (mostly) present aggregate numbers. Also, the outbreak is still young and is not yet fully processed in databases. So with better data we might be better able to see the impact of the disease (I suspect that the agencies have better information).

So the fact that we currently see little influence of Covid-19 on aggregated statistics of death rate is not reassuring because it is meaningless to look at aggregated statistics (this depends a bit on your philosophy about nature and death though, personally I feel we are overreacting, but that is completely different from statistics).

See also this note from [EuroMomo](https://www.euromomo.eu/outputs/zscore_country_total.html)

> **Note concerning COVID-19 related mortality as part of the all-cause mortality figures reported by EuroMOMO**
>
> Over the past few days, the EuroMOMO hub has received many questions about the weekly all-cause mortality data and the possible contribution of any COVID-19 related mortality. Some wonder why no increased mortality is observed in the reported mortality figures for the COVID-19 affected countries.
> The answer is that increased mortality that may occur primarily at subnational level or within smaller focal areas, and/or concentrated within smaller age groups, may not be detected at the overall national level. This even more so in the pooled European-wide analysis, given the large total population denominator. Furthermore, there is always a few weeks of delay in death registration and reporting. Hence, the EuroMOMO mortality figures for the most recent weeks must be interpreted with some caution.
> Therefore, although increased mortality is currently not being observed in the EuroMOMO figures, this does not mean that increased mortality does not occur in some areas or in some age groups, including mortality related to COVID-19.

Comment: It is definitely a bit too early to expect interesting results in highly aggregated data. I guess for most countries you would need data per day, but unfortunately I suspect that monthly data will be sufficient soon as well for the top countries. -- And though I almost missed it, it seems that EuroMOMO actually has graphs from which you can roughly infer numbers. Thanks!

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin regarding the corona-virus cases we have data per day and we could use the trick to compare those with the cases per day that would normally happen during the season... but, I guess that you would like to look at death rates in order to get rid of all the data collection problems which relates to the diffuculties of assigning a death to a particular root cause which might create biased statistics (what is the cause of death for a person that went to the hospital due to influenza and aqcuired covid19 in the hospital?). For that purpose the trick will not work.